# Are there any examples of people being able to predict the consequences of communication revolutions?

Tags: technology, communication, sociology, crowd-psychology

I often read predictions about future technologies from analysis companies like Gartner Group. These studies often strike me as awfully linear in their view on development. I would, therefore, like to know examples of people who have been able to predict the consequences of technologies that have radically changed communication. I use a very broad definition of communication, to include transportation infrastructure, so predictions on the impact of things like a postal service, the train, the automobile, telegraph or a modern thing like Twitter are all interesting.

Comment: An analyst can tell you tomorrow why, what he predicted yesterday, did not happen today.

Comment: @Sardathrion nice aphorism, reminds me on *"I know not with what weapons World War III will be fought, but World War IV will be fought with sticks and stones."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "[Global Village](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Village_%28term%29)" (todays metaphor for the world wide web) comes to my mind, predicted by probably most influential communication theorist **[Marshall McLuhan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_McLuhan)**.

In his book, "The Gutenberg Galaxy" (1962), he basically predicts PC, WorldWideWeb, Wikipedia, Google, social-media, e-commerce everybody uses today in the western world:

> “The next medium, whatever it is — it may be the extension of consciousness — will include television as its content, not as its environment, and will transform television into an art form. A computer as a research and communication instrument could enhance retrieval, obsolesce mass library organization, retrieve the individual’s encyclopedic function and flip it into a private line to speedily tailored data of a saleable kind.”

Be aware, there were still in the late 70s entrepeneurs doubting a market for personal computer:

> «There is no reason anyone would want a computer in their home.»
>   (Ken Olson, president, chairman and founder of Digital Equipment Corp. (DEC), maker of big business mainframe computers, arguing against the PC in 1977. )

An important position of McLuhan and other theorist like [**Jacques Ellul**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Ellul) is the concept of [*Technological Determinism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_determinism). Ellul's book [*Technological Society*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006AXXY4) (1964) forecasted many developments and problems modern societies face. Really an eye-opener and well written.

Comment: Wow, that is amazingly prescient of McLuhan.